boost::mysql error on destroying the connection object
I'm using Boost.MySQL library from the boost packages for c++. I have encountered an error when creating and destroying a database connection using local io_context and ssl_contexts.
Please see the minimal reproducible example below -

class DatabaseProcess : public MainframeComponent
{
public:
    // MainframeComponent dispatch module type is set to Main because DatabaseProcess doesn't run on its own thread.
    DatabaseProcess() : MainframeComponent(Horizon::System::RUNTIME_DATABASE) { }
    ~DatabaseProcess() 
    { 
    }
    
    void initialize(int segment_number = 1) override { HLog(error) << "Database not configured"; }
    void initialize(int segment_number, std::string host, int port, std::string user, std::string pass, std::string database);

    void finalize(int segment_number = 1) override 
    {
        // Close connection object.
        if (_connection != nullptr) {
            _connection->close();
        }
        
        bool value = _is_initialized;
        _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, false);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> get_connection() { return _connection; }

    bool is_initialized() { return _is_initialized.load(); }
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> _ssl_ctx{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection{nullptr};
    boost::asio::io_context _db_io_context;
    std::atomic<bool> _is_initialized;
};

void DatabaseProcess::initialize(int segment_number, std::string host, int port, std::string user, std::string pass, std::string database)
{
    try {
        _ssl_ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tls_client);
        _connection = std::make_shared<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection>(_db_io_context.get_executor(), *_ssl_ctx);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_db_io_context.get_executor());
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(host, std::to_string(port));
        boost::mysql::handshake_params params(user, pass, database);
        _connection->connect(*endpoints.begin(), params);
    } catch (boost::mysql::error_with_diagnostics &error) {
        HLog(error) << error.what();
    }

    bool value = _is_initialized;
    _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, true);
}



Firstly, please actually make the code self-contained. Secondly, how is this question different from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/78741201/85371] and is there a particular (preferrably convincing) reason to refuse the simplifications suggested there? Note that my simplified version already carefully avoided the exact issue you had here.

Actually making it self-contained:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/mysql.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

#define HLog(level)                                                                                          \
    std::osyncstream(std::cerr) << "\n[" #level "] " << std::filesystem::path(__FILE__).filename().native()  \
                                << ":" << __LINE__ << ":\t"

namespace Horizon { namespace System {
    enum MainframeComponentType {
        RUNTIME_DATABASE      = 0,
        RUNTIME_WEBSERVER     = 1,
        RUNTIME_WEBSOCKET     = 2,
        RUNTIME_LOGGER        = 3,
        RUNTIME_SCHEDULER     = 4,
        RUNTIME_CONTROLLER    = 5,
        RUNTIME_MONITOR       = 6,
        RUNTIME_SECURITY      = 7,
        RUNTIME_COMMUNICATION = 8,
        RUNTIME_OTHER         = 9
    };
}} // namespace Horizon::System


struct MainframeComponent
{
    MainframeComponent(int type) : _type(type) {}
    virtual ~MainframeComponent()                   = default;
    virtual void initialize(int segment_number = 1) = 0;
    virtual void finalize(int segment_number = 1) = 0;
    int _type;
};

class DatabaseProcess : public MainframeComponent {
  public:
    // MainframeComponent dispatch module type is set to Main because DatabaseProcess doesn't run on its own thread.
    DatabaseProcess() : MainframeComponent(Horizon::System::RUNTIME_DATABASE) { }
    ~DatabaseProcess() = default;

    void initialize(int /*segment_number*/ = 1) override { HLog(error) << "Database not configured"; }
    void initialize(int segment_number, std::string host, int port, std::string user, std::string pass,
                    std::string database);

    void finalize(int /*segment_number*/ = 1) override {
        // Close connection object.
        if (_connection != nullptr) {
            _connection->close();
        }

        _is_initialized = false;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> get_connection() { return _connection; }

    bool is_initialized() { return _is_initialized.load(); }

  protected:
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context>        _ssl_ctx;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection;
    boost::asio::io_context                           _db_io_context;
    std::atomic<bool>                                 _is_initialized{false};
};

void DatabaseProcess::initialize(int /*segment_number*/, std::string host, int port, std::string user,
                                 std::string pass, std::string database) {
    try {
        _ssl_ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(boost::asio::ssl::context::tls_client);
        _connection =
            std::make_shared<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection>(_db_io_context.get_executor(), *_ssl_ctx);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_db_io_context.get_executor());
        auto                           endpoints = resolver.resolve(host, std::to_string(port));
        boost::mysql::handshake_params params(user, pass, database);
        _connection->connect(*endpoints.begin(), params);
        HLog(info) << "Database connection established to " << host << ":" << port << " as " << user << " to "
                   << database << " database.";
    } catch (boost::mysql::error_with_diagnostics& error) {
        HLog(error) << error.what();
    }

    bool value = _is_initialized;
    _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, true);
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io_context;
    DatabaseProcess db;
    db.initialize(1, "localhost", 3306, "root", "root", "test");

    io_context.run();
}

Running with sanitizers:

Clearly, your IO object (and operations) outlive the io services (inside io_context).
Since you're not using any async operations you should be fine if you switch the declaration order such that _connection is destructed before _db_io_context etc. So change
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context>        _ssl_ctx;
std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection;
boost::asio::io_context                           _db_io_context;
std::atomic<bool>                                 _is_initialized{false};

To
std::atomic<bool>                                 _is_initialized{false};
boost::asio::io_context                           _db_io_context;
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context>        _ssl_ctx;
std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection;

Now the issue is gone:

